# "The C++ Programming Language" confusion on Comparison

Tags: c++, c++11

I am not grasping the idea from this quote by Stroustrup on page 862 of "The C++ Programming Language" 4th edition at the end of the first paragraph (I've highlighted the relevant portion):

> Building the comparison criteria into a sort function is unacceptable because the same
>   data can be sorted according to different criteria. This is why the C standard-library `qsort()` takes a
>   comparison function as an argument rather than relying on something fixed, say, the `<` operator.
>
> On the other hand, the overhead imposed by a function call for each comparison compromises `qsort()` as a building block for further library building. **For almost every data type, it is easy to do a comparison without imposing the overhead of a function call.**
>
> Is that overhead serious? In most cases, probably not. However, the function call overhead can dominate the execution time for some algorithms and cause users to seek alternatives.

What is an example of a comparison that is not a function?
Why does providing a template comparison to a stl algorithm such as `std::sort` could directly compare instead of invoking a function call?

Comment: `1 < 2`............

Comment: I mainly wanted ask why providing a template comparison to a stl algorithm such as std::sort could directly compare instead of invoking a function call.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a *little* hard to be certain when you take such a short quote out of context, but I'd assume that he's pointing to the fact that comparisons of simple objects normally don't involve any function calls.

For example, consider code like:

```
std::vector<int> a { 19, 7, 1, 144, 14, 10, 5};

std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
```

In this case, the code to compare one `int` to another will normally be generated inline, removing the overhead of calling a function to compare the numbers. From a syntactical viewpoint, what's being used is a function instantiated from a function template (`std::less<T>`, to be exact). But, when you look at the generated code, the tiny bit of code for `std::less<T>` will normally be generated inline, so there's no function call overhead.

This is a decided contrast to (for one obvious comparison) `qsort` from the C standard library. It has the generated object code for `qsort` itself in the standard library, and that code is written to invoke the comparison via a pointer to a function. If you wanted to generate code inline for this case, that would have to be built as a link-time (not compile-time) optimization.

This is (most of?) why using `std::sort` (as above) will typically be substantially faster than using `qsort`, especially when dealing with types that are really simple to compare, such as the `int`s used here. In this case, you can typically expect `std::sort` to be around three times as fast as `qsort`.

Comment: Stroustrup went on to say that supplying comparison criteria through a template argument solves that problem for sort(). Does it generate the code inline to do the comparison? Else the overhead for calling the function is still there.

Comment: That is exactly what I am confused of. Thank you very much, your answer makes complete sense!